# How to get data in json or download json file from a website created by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, security, developer-tools

I have created a website using React. In the website, some json files are imported using `json-loader`.

I would like to know if the json files can be extracted/downloaded by visitors.

I tried Google Developer Tools along with React Developer Tool extension but can't seem to find a way to get the data of the json files.

The reason is that I just want to test if the json files could be extracted/downloaded externally for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, they almost certainly could be. Look through your network tab.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did, but couldn't find the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `json-loader` module converts a `json` file into a module that is imported into the code and merged into a bundle.

If you import a `json` file in this way, it is treated as a source code.

However, when you try to request a `json` file as a file from `http-server`, you are asking a server to search for a file within the website's static content.

If `json` file is not listed in the static content folder, the server won't be able to find it.

On the other hand, from a security perspective, nothing prevents users from downloading your `react` bundle and extracting `json` data from it. If the data is sensitive, you shouldn't include it in your bundle nor expose it through your http-server. To protect it, you will have to keep it on the backend and provide the front-end with an API to request the processed/partially less sensitive parts of your data to front-end.